# player vimeo override play button css

Tags: css

I have this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2CZg/)

Here's a screenshot from Chrome Canary:
[image]

What am trying to do is adding the following code

```
.player .controls button.play {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    border-radius: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgba(23,35,34,.75) !important;
}
```

but that doesn't work for, any help will be thankful. 
Cheers

Comment: it has a `border-radius` and `background-color` !

Comment: @Mohsen I wanna override them!

Answer (score 0):

It has `border-radius` and `background-color`. but you can change it. here is the class:

```
.player .rounded-box {
background: rgba(23,35,34,.75);
border-radius: .5em;
}
```

[image]

***note:*** this is in `iframe` so, you need to have the style sheet file.

Answer (score 0):

Well after searching I've found the following:

No it can’t.

The iframe in Page A is just a container element which links to the page in iframe B. Thus iframe B will only adhere to the CSS included within its page. There is no way to override this, unless of course they share the same stylesheet.

If we could override the CSS then we’d notice more customized Adsense Ads floating about on the web.

So no luck, thanks for your time.